# ASP.Net core RC2 migration csproj reference errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a `utils.csproj` which I reference in my `ASP.Net Core RC2` application. Problem is that while everything works fine in runtime(so RC2 finds dependencies and runs them), I can even debug it, in compile time visual studio highlights everything by red, because it cannot resolve `usings`. It's bizzare becuase in RC1 with `dnx452` everything was working. But now every `using` reference to my custom asselmbly is ignored (are you missign a reference?), thus every usage of its classes in `.cs` file leads to an error. It's hard do develop when every file in project has tens of red lines, number of errors in project is over multiple hundreds, when project builds and runs, but I have no intellisense, resharper also is not working. I just should edit my code in `notepad++` or something, becuase VS is driven crazy and cannot help me.

I downloaded VS2015 Update 3 which is released 2 days ago, but it didn't fix it. 
I can't create an issue in `cli` because it's not problem with `cli` - project runs and works fine, but I don't know where can I get a hotfix. But maybe there is someone here who knows how to fix it?

My dependencies:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Services.Interfaces": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "NetUtils": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Utils": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true, // Yes, please perform garbage collection
    "gcConcurrent": true // Yes, please do so concurrently...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

Comment: Did you uninstall all the old stuff like dnx and rc1?

Comment: @Fabian no I didn't. AFAIK they doesn't interfer with each other. And as I said there is no problem with tooling, but with VS itself, tooling is working fine: app runs and works.

Comment: Do it. As far as I remember I had the same problem. MS explicitly advise you to do so.

Comment: @Fabian i deleted everything with `dnvm uninstall`, then deleted `.dnx` folder, then removed every file containing `dnx` or `dnvm` keyword, then I rerunned `DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools` with `repair` option. It didn't help.

Comment: Try to uninstall the RC1 CLI from installed programs (Programs and Features => "Microsoft Dotnet CLI for Windows (1.0.0.XXXX)")

Comment: @Fabian nice, I did it, but now unable to install it again: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3371 ...

Comment: Well, I fixed it by removing visual studio and 2015 C++ redistrutables, but at now I'm finishing. I wasted a lot of time, and removed MSVS, multiple software and so on without any positive result. If someone has an info how could it be fixed, I'd appreciate its sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was related to outdated `project.json` file. I recreated a project and added all files, and it fixed it.